# Getting Empty List in mysql IN operator

Tags: java, mysql

I am using In operator for fetching data using mysql.If the list has value,then I am getting the data in a proper manner . For example,

```
SELECT * FROM featured_service_provider where user_id IN (1,2)
```

If I am passing empty from front end ,I am getting the query as,

```
SELECT * FROM featured_service_provider where user_id IN ()
```

How can I handle this?if the list is empty ,I need to get all the userid from the table? IS this possible?

Comment: Don't use the where condition.

Comment: Why not just skip the where... part all together?

Comment: Actually I need to pass data or empty list from java side.. @joa

Comment: If I pass any negative number , I wont get any UserID ? right? Autually I need to get all the userid from the table

Comment: A NOT IN(some negative value) would give you all but I guess that's not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the whole `where` clause optional.

Use a `StringBuilder` to create the default part of the query which is `SELECT * FROM featured_service_provider`. Then add the `where` clause if needed:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("SELECT * FROM featured_service_provider");
if(list.size > 0) {
    sb.append("where user_id IN (:list)");
}
```

I am not sure how you create the query in the end, but you need to replace `:list` with the comma-separated list of values.

If you use Hibernate, then `Criteria` might also be worth a look

Comment: In my case , I am using JPA repository

Comment: Then `Criteria` is an option too. [Here are a few information](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html), but I think they are a bit outdated